# Best/Easiest/Quickest way to get relative path between two files?

Tags: scripting, file, directory

I'm in the midst of some refactoring some C# code and part of this is to redo some references, because we're redoing the folder structure entirely. What I'd like to do is just go into the .csproj or .sln file and modify the paths.

However some of the references have paths like

```
"../../../../../../ThirdParty/SomeMicrosoftLibrary/bin/Debug/SomeMicrosoftLibrary.dll
```

And since we've moved everything around I need to find the new relative path. But I absolutely hate trying to do this (figure out how many slashes and periods I need to put in) since it always feels like some hit or miss science.

Is there some easy way (utility, script, snippet of code) to say "here's file A, here's file B, what is the relative path of file B in relation to file A?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generate a Relative Path](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13737)

It's in Java, but easily translatable to C#.

Answer (score 8):

With Ruby:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'pathname'; puts Pathname.new('foo/bar').relative_path_from(Pathname.new('baz/x/y/z')).to_s"
../../../../foo/bar
```

I'm pretty sure Python has a similar method, though I don't have it handy.

Comment: I don't think there's such a method in Python's standard library, but a Google search turns up plenty of examples.

Comment: *checks*  Isn't it just os.path.relpath(a, b)?

Comment: I'd marry Ruby if it was possible =)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I was looking for the answer to this so here's a method which does it, just in case it might help anyone else out in the future

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the relative path of B with respect to A
/// </summary>
/// <param name="A">The path you're navigating from</param>
/// <param name="B">The path you're navigating to</param>
/// <returns></returns>
static string Get_PathB_wrt_PathA(string A, string B)
{
    string result = "";

    if (A == B)
        return result;

    var s = new char[] { '\\' };
    var subA = A.Split(s, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    var subB = B.Split(s, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    int L = subA.Count >= subB.Count ? subB.Count : subA.Count;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        if (subA[0] == subB[0])
        {
            subA.RemoveAt(0);
            subB.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= subA.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        result += @"..\"; //this navigates to the preceding directory
    }

    for (i = 0; i < subB.Count; i++)
    {
        result += subB[i] + "\\";
    }

    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1); //remove the extra backslash
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a check to make sure that 'result' HAS a trailing backslash before trying to take the substring? If A and B are the exact same paths, this will fail. I don't write C#, but in other languages it will produce an exception because you try to take a substring with length -1.

Comment: Additionally, if A and B are equal, your for loops become infinite. (subA.Count - 1) = (0 - 1) = -1, which will never satisfy the loop terminating condtion: i < -1. The loop simply increments i forever. Again, not familiar with C# so maybe there's some language features that prevent that. But in other languages, the pattern above needs some safety checks.

Comment: I added a check for A == B, since it's a waste to run the rest of the logic if we already know they're equal.  The loop would not be infinite if they were equal though.  All of the loops are positive-incrementing For loops, there's no danger of one not terminating.  Additionally, with regard to the trailing backslash, I changed the condition in the second loop to be a <= instead of a < (that was a bug) and with the check at the top for A and B being equal, there should no longer be any cases where the string wouldn't end with an extra backslash